# Custom ImageComboBox not always behaving the same way

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox

I have created a custom `comboBox` that supports images in front of the items text. Here's how it looks:
[image: ImageComboBox]

For this, I created a new control called `ImageComboBox` that is stored in a `dll` referenced in my winforms project.
This `ImageComboBox` is nothing more than a `ComboBox` with `DrawMode` set to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` and holding a [`ImageList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx) that contains all images to draw. There is a `DrawItemEventHandler` that is in charge of drawing the image and the text of each item.

I encounter a two-pixel problem, but the confusing part is that the problem is not always occurring. When I create a new winforms project and simply add a new `ImageComboBox`, I don't have the problem. When I add a new `ImageComboBox` on a winforms project rather advanced, the problem occurs - 9 times out of 10 times (or something like that).

---

Here's the step to reproduce my two-pixel problem:

1. When I open the form, everything's fine:
   [image: First step]
2. When I drop down the `imageComboBox`, everything's fine:
   [image: Second step]
3. When I hover an item to select it, everything's fine:
   [image: Third step]
4. When I select an item, everything's fine:
   [image: Fourth step]
5. And when I drop down the `imageComboBox` when there is an item selected, the problem occurs: the image in front of the selected item is shifted by two pixels on the right and the text is shifted by one pixel on the left:
   [image: Fifth step]
   Let's zoom:
   [image: Fifth step - zoomed]
6. And here the proof I don't have the bug sometimes:
   [image: Fifth step - no bug]
   Let's zoom again:
   [image: Fifth step - no bug - zoomed]

---

Here's the `DrawItemEvent` of my `ImageComboBox`:
(`this._imageList` is my `ImageList` object)

```
private void OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Index >= 0) {
        // If the current item is one in the comboBox

        // Compute the X location of the text to drawn
        int strLocationX = this._imageList.Images.Count > e.Index ?
                this._imageList.Images[e.Index].Width + 1 :
                e.Bounds.X + 1;

        // Get the displayed text of the current item
        String itemText = this.Items[e.Index].ToString();

        if (this.DroppedDown) {
            // If the comboBox is dropped down

            // Draw the blue rectangle
            e.DrawBackground();

            if (e.State == DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) {
                // If we are drawing the selected item

                // Draw the text
                e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 
                    new Point(strLocationX + 1, e.Bounds.Y + 1));

                if (this._imageList.Images.Count > e.Index) {
                    // If we have an image available

                    // Draw the image
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(this._imageList.Images[e.Index],
                        new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y - 1));
                }

            } else {
                // If we are drawing one of the item in the drop down

                // Check if the item is being highlighted
                if (e.State.ToString().Contains(DrawItemState.Focus.ToString()) &&
                    e.State.ToString().Contains(DrawItemState.Selected.ToString())) {
                    // Draw the text in White
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, this.Font, Brushes.White, 
                        new Point(strLocationX, e.Bounds.Y + 1));
                } else {
                    // Draw the text in Black
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 
                        new Point(strLocationX, e.Bounds.Y + 1));
                }

                if (this._imageList.Images.Count > e.Index) {
                    // If we have an image available

                    // Draw the image
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(this._imageList.Images[e.Index],
                        new Point(e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y - 1));
                }
            }
        } else {
            // If the comboBox is not dropped down

            // Draw the text
            e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 
                new Point(strLocationX + 1, e.Bounds.Y + 1));

            if (this._imageList.Images.Count > e.Index) {
                // If we have an image available

                // Draw the image
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(this._imageList.Images[e.Index],
                    new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y - 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my point of view, the code should be right, but it seems that sometimes the `if` conditions don't return the same results whereas I think it should do.

Any clue on where this problem could come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: the code was not right, I had a wrong `if` condition at the beginning of the snippet (but I still don't understand why the bug was happening sometimes and sometimes not).

I have to use:

```
if (this.DroppedDown) {
    // If the comboBox is dropped down

    // Draw the blue rectangle
    e.DrawBackground();

    if (( e.State & DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit ) == DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) {
        // If we are drawing the selected item

        // ...
```

instead of:

```
if (this.DroppedDown) {
    // If the comboBox is dropped down

    // Draw the blue rectangle
    e.DrawBackground();

    if (e.State == DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) {
        // If we are drawing the selected item

        // ...
```